# Does a Ger have a Chiyuv to get an Aliya?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, torah-service

<sup>Inspired by the comments to [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97019/501) about (*pseudo*) 2nd Bar Mitzvahs.</sup>

Both the [Magen Avraham](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Magen_Avraham.282.18?vhe=Magen_Avraham&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in 282:18 and the [Biur Halocho](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Biur_Halacha.136.1.1?vhe=Biur_Halacha&lang=bi) in 136:1:1 mention that the reason a Bar Mitzva boy has a high priority to get an Aliya laTorah is because he's being inaugurated into Mitzvoth.

> ונער בר מצוה באותו שבת אם  יש לו עירנית דוחה לכל החיובים **כיון שהוא יום חינוכו**‏

From that I understand that since it's his first chance to get an Aliya, he should be given precedence over (almost) all other people.

Following that logic it would seem that a Ger Tzedek should also be given precedence for an Aliya laTorah immediately after his conversion.

However, I cannot find a source to back up that claim.

Anybody know of a source, or else, a reason why the Ger doesn't deserve preferential treatment?

Comment: ישראל קודם לגר. https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/משנה_הוריות_ג_ח

Comment: @DoubleAA - based on that logic he'd never get an Aliya unless the entire Minyan are Gerim (or just about)...

Comment: Maybe In Hachi Nami. And maybe in general we don't want to embarrass him, but we're not going to go out of our way to give him a special Chiyuv.

Comment: @DannySchoemann On the contrary, based on that logic, he gets the coveted *shishi*.

Comment: He *should* because we have the added mitzvah to love the ger.

Comment: @chacham so give him a hug. Aliyot don't indicate love.